# Is it possible to @XmlElement annotate a method with non-stardard name?

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

This is what I'm doing:

```
@XmlType(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public final class Foo {
  @XmlElement(name = "title")
  public String title() {
    return "hello, world!";
  }
}
```

JAXB complains:

```
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
JAXB annotation is placed on a method that is not a JAXB property
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement(nillable=false, name=title, required=false, defaultValue=, type=class javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement$DEFAULT, namespace=##default)
        at com.example.Foo
```

What to do? I don't want (and can't) rename the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a better way, but the first solution that comes to mind is:

```
@XmlElement(name = "title")
private String title;

public String getTitle() {
    return title();
}
```

Why is it you can't name your method according to Java conventions anyway?

Comment: Variable is redundant here, just `@XmlElement`-annotated `getTitle()` will be enough

Comment: I wasn't sure, so I put it in just in case as that will definitely work.

Comment: +1 - When annotating a field (instance variable) that has a corresponding accessor you will want to be sure to set @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html.  Also in this case JAXB will apply a default mapping for the title property so the `@XmlElement` annotation is not required.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of different options:

**Option #1 - Introduce a Field**

If the value is constant as it is in your example, then you could introduce a field into your domain class and have JAXB map to that:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public final class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    private final String title = "hello, world!";

  public String title() {
    return title;
  }
}
```

**Option #2 - Introduce a Property**

If the value is calculated then you will need to introduce a JavaBean accessor and have JAXB map to that:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlType(name = "foo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public final class Foo {

  public String title() {
    return "hello, world!";
  }

  @XmlElement
  public String getTitle() {
      return title();
  }

}
```

Comment: Than why do I need `title()` at all?

Comment: @yegor256 - JAXB would not require the `title()` method.

Comment: But I require it :) I need `title()` to return the value. The solution proposed by Thor84no is the best at the moment, but I really hope that it's not the only one. Again, value has to be returned by `title()`

Comment: @yegor256 - As shown in my code sample you can definitely have the `title()` method, it just isn't used by the JAXB implementation.  Is the value returned from the `title()` method constant or calculated?

Comment: Since the value is calculated then you will need to introduce a get method as given by Thor84no.  I would not introduce the field as is specified in that answer however.  I have updated my answer with how it should look.

Comment: Yes, I understand, thanks. This is what Thor84no suggested already. If this is the only solution I will select his answer, since he was the first.

Comment: This does not appear to work without a corresponding "setTitle(String)" method also defined.  Even if you use @XmlWriteOnly with Moxy.  It simply ignores the field.